# How to get access to my index from another function?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, indexing

I want to destroy objects from my list Prefab[] in my function update, but I haven't figured out how I can access the index of the list in another function. Do you have any idea how I can do it ?

Here is my code :

```
public GameObject[] Prefab;
public Transform[] spawnPoint;
public Transform player;
public AudioClip[] sonAnimaux ;
private int i = 0;
private int j = 0;
private int k = 0;
private float delay = 3f;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    // fonction on l'on fait apparaitre les objets de la liste selon son empty

    while (i<Prefab.Length && j < spawnPoint.Length && k < sonAnimaux.Length )  {

        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Instantiate(Prefab[i] , spawnPoint[j].position, spawnPoint[j].rotation);
        audio.clip = sonAnimaux[k];
        audio.Play();
        i++;
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void Update() {
    Destroy(Prefab[i],delay);
    Debug.Log("The object" + Prefab[i]);
}
```

I want to Destroy Prefab[i] but I dont know how to get my index list in another function.

Comment: It depends on where you want to call update from. You should be able to just pass it as parameter.

Comment: i want my Prefab[i] object be destroyed after 3 seconds , so i just have to pass the prefab[] list in my update function parameter? like this ? :
void update(Prefab[i]) ? @PalleDue

Comment: @kehalS: More like `void Update(int i)`.

Comment: But stop me if i am wrong, the update function doesnt take any parameter right ?@waka

Comment: Are you trying to create a prefab then destroy it after 3sec?

Comment: @kehalS Right now it doesn't, no.

Comment: Also there is a difference between destroying the prefab and destroying the new instance (clone) of a prefab.

Comment: why doing this in `Udpate` **at all**? Just do it in the method that actually should destroy it ... currently `i` is a **field** so there should be no issue with access it .. I guess you rather have the issue that this `i` doesn't have the value you expect and note that `Update` is called **every frame** so your code makes not much sense to me currently since already in the next frame your `i` will be invalid since you already destroyed that object

Answer (score 2):

From the context of your comments, it looks like what you're trying to achieve is destroying a clone with some delay after instantiation.

As others have suggested, Destroy does not need to be called from update and you'll need the instantiated object's reference. Using Destroy with your `Prefab` array will destroy the prefab instead.

```cs
public GameObject[] Prefab;
public Transform[] spawnPoint;
public Transform player;
public AudioClip[] sonAnimaux ;
private int i = 0;
private int j = 0;
private int k = 0;
private float delay = 3f;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    // fonction on l'on fait apparaitre les objets de la liste selon son empty

    while (i<Prefab.Length && j < spawnPoint.Length && k < sonAnimaux.Length )  {

        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        // Get the instantiated GameObject's reference
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(Prefab[i] , spawnPoint[j].position, spawnPoint[j].rotation);
        // Queue the object for destruction
        Destroy(clone, delay);
        Debug.Log("The object" + Prefab[i]); // If you still need it, move your Log call

        audio.clip = sonAnimaux[k];
        audio.Play();
        i++;
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

**Immediately queuing the GameObject for destruction appears to make your current Update function obsolete, so I've removed it for brevity.*

Comment: Exactly what I would have done, if I knew Unity ;-) keHals: I think you should accept this answer.

Comment: you also don't need i, j and k since the smallest of all three collection will prevail. And they all end up being the same. If they all are same size collections then a for loop is enough. But there is a secondary issue there, you are always reaching to the same AudioSource and reassigning a new audio to it, it will only play the last audio.

Comment: Better solution would be to have the AudioSource on the prefabs then have them play on Awake so need to assign and play, it will be done automatically. It also makes more sense since the audio will use 3D space while now it is all on that manager object.

Comment: @Joe `keHals wants to destroy the instantiated object` true that, sorry!

Comment: @Everts - both true, but I was trying to answer the current issue that is presented, rather than provide a code review. Perhaps keHals had some other use for those counters in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing all I said so far.

Update your prefabs to have an AudioSource attached with the appropriate audio file. Then set them to play on awake. This will remove the need for audio code.

Assuming also that you have the same amount of prefabs and spawn points.

then you are left with:

```
public GameObject[] Prefab;
public Transform[] spawnPoint;
private float delay = 3f;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Prefabs.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(Prefab[i], spawnPoint[i].position, spawnPoint[i].rotation);
        Destroy(clone, delay);
    }
}
```

If you do not have the same amount of prefabs and spawn points then you need to run the smallest collection so you avoid an out of bounds exception:

```
private int size;

void Awake()
{
    size = (Prefabs.Length < spawnPoint.Length) ? Prefabs.Length : spawnPoint.Length;
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        GameObject clone = Instantiate(Prefab[i], spawnPoint[i].position, spawnPoint[i].rotation);
        Destroy(clone, delay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Unity, but I suppose `Update` is a virtual method and you cannot change the parameters. In that case you can do something like this:

```cs
public GameObject[] Prefab;
public Transform[] spawnPoint;
public Transform player;
public AudioClip[] sonAnimaux ;
private int i = 0;
private int j = 0;
private int k = 0;
private float delay = 3f;

private int indexToDelete = -1;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    // fonction on l'on fait apparaitre les objets de la liste selon son empty

    while (i<Prefab.Length && j < spawnPoint.Length && k < sonAnimaux.Length )  {

        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Instantiate(Prefab[i] , spawnPoint[j].position, spawnPoint[j].rotation);
        indexToDelete = i;
        audio.clip = sonAnimaux[k];
        audio.Play();
        i++;
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void Update() {
    if (indexToDelete>=0 && indexToDelete<Prefab.Length)
    {
        Destroy(Prefab[indexToDelete], delay);
        Debug.Log("The object" + Prefab[indexToDelete]);
    }
}
```

This assumes that `OnTriggerEnter` and `Update` are in the same class, so they can share the value of the member `indexToDelete`. Otherwise you will have to implement some kind of messaging.

Comment: This is going to destroy the prefab but not the new instance. Also, why running an update when you can call the destroy in the trigger method since you use the delay. This is about to try and destroy the same object many times. But since you are destroying the prefab, the clone is still there.

Comment: Also, there is no point in having indexToDelete, i, j and k since they are the same value.

Comment: @Everts: I didn't want to go into that discussion, but just wanted to show a way of fixing keHals code.

Comment: @Everts: I assumed the other indices could be changed elsewhere in code, so I introduced one that wouldn't.

Comment: yeah exactly @Everts , i dont know how i can destroy the clone right now ? any idea ?

Comment: you need to keep the reference out of the Instantiate and destroy that reference

Comment: also note: after destroying once the element is still a part of the `Prefab` array .. but with value `null` .. so next frame you are trying to do `Destroy(null)` and will get an exception.